# ELAN touchpad works incorrectly

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, touchpad

I installed Ubuntu through virtualbox on my laptop. There are 2 problems with my touchpad:
1. Vertical 2-finger scrolling speed is super-fast, I need to slow it down
2. Horizontal scrolling does not work.
Here are some commands I performed:

```
miroslav@TuringMachine:~$ xinput 
⎡ Virtual core pointer                  id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer        id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox mouse integration      id=9    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ VirtualBox USB Tablet             id=10   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ImExPS/2 Generic Explorer Mouse   id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                 id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard       id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                      id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                      id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                         id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard      id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
```

The funny thing is device 9 is responsible for 1-finger motions but for 2-finger scrolling only device 12 is responsible:

```
miroslav@TuringMachine:~$ xinput --test 12 
motion a[3]=-1
button press   5
button release 5
motion a[3]=-2
button press   5
button release 5
motion a[3]=-3
button press   5
button release 5
motion a[3]=-4
button press   5
button release 5
```

It seems like 2-finger scrolling is done by emulating of pressing buttons. But I can't adjust the speed of it, because nothing in `xinput list-props 12` changes the speed. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this with `xinput set-prop 12 "Evdev Scrolling Distance" 5, 5, 5`